# Liquibase class missing from 1.9 to 2.0.3

Tags: java, liquibase

While I was doing a Liquibase update from 1.9 to 2.0.3, FileSystemFileOpener.java seemed to be missing.

Can anyone please tell me if there is a replacement to FileSystemFileOpener.java in 2.0.3 version and where can I find those kind of changes done in 2.0.3 version from ?

Comment: I would suggest posting onto the liquibase mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is now liquibase.resource.FileSystemResourceAccessor